# Can I make Plot show only one axesorigin?

Tags: plotting

[![enter image description here][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvStC.png
**Is there any way to make it show only one "AxesOrigin"(0.0) instead of two? Should I change the code of "FrameTicks"?**
thanks! here is my code:

```
\[Beta] = 0.9;
y1 = -(((-2 + \[Beta])^2 (-1 + \[Beta]^2))/(4 (4 - 3 \[Beta]^2)^2)) ;
y2 = ((-1 + \[Beta]) (-8 + (-6 + \[Beta]) \[Beta])^2 (-1 + \[Phi]))/(4 (1 + \[Beta]) (-8 + \[Beta]^2 (4 + \[Phi]))^2);
y3 = -(((-1 + \[Beta]^2) (-2 + \[Beta] + \[Beta] \[Phi])^2)/(-8 +\[Beta]^2 (6 + \[Phi]))^2);
y4 = ((-1 + \[Beta]) (-4 + (-2 + \[Beta]) \[Beta])^2 (-1 + \[Phi]))/(16 (1 + \[Beta]) (-2 + \[Beta]^2)^2); 
Plot[{y1,y2,y3,y4},{\[Phi],0,0.2},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{\[Phi],"Profit"},FrameStyle ->Directive[Black,Bold],LabelStyle -> Directive[Black,12,FontFamily->"Times New Roman"],FrameTicks->{{Range[0,1,0.2], 1, True}, {All, Automatic},SetPrecision[#, 2]},PlotRange -> {{0,0.2}, {0,0.5}},PlotStyle->{{Black, Dashed},{Hue[9/6], Bold,{Red,DotDashed}, {Blue, Dashing[Large]}}, AspectRatio -> 4/5,PlotRangePadding->None}]
```

Comment: by the way, I want it show "0" rather than (0.0)

Comment: your code does not run, lots of syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

Since your code does not run (it has lots of syntax errors), I made one up

```
 Plot[1 - x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To remove the zero on the `y` axis, one option would be

```
Plot[1 - x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][0.1, 1, {5, 5}], 
    None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To remove the zero on the `x` axis

```
Plot[1 - x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
    None}, {Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][0.1, 1, {5, 5}], None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

may be you can adopt this to your actual code.

Comment: Thanks ! I edit my question again and attach my code!